# Indian language Malayalam not available on Keyboard Layouts

Tags: language

I have been trying to install the keyboard layout I use to type my regional language but the language is not shown in keyboard layou

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings -> Keyboards -> click the + icon at the lower-left corner and select Indian. Then you can see all the Indian language keyboard layouts listed. I think this what you are looking for.